# Pdf file upload by cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp

I am new in cakephp.I can upload pdf file by php.Now I want to upload pdf file by cakephp.Can anybody suggest me a best reference?

Upload pdf file by php code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="upload3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="filepdf" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload menu pdf" name="upload_pdf" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>


php file 

<?php

    $pdfPath = "pdf";
    $maxSize = 102400000000;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['upload_pdf'])) {   
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filepdf']['tmp_name'])) {
            if ($_FILES['filepdf']['type'] != "application/pdf") {
                echo '<p>Il file non &#232; un PDF</p>';
            } else if ($_FILES['filepdf']['size'] > $maxSize) {
                echo '<p class="error">File troppo grande. Dimensione massima: ' . $maxSize . 'KB</p>';
            } else {
                $menuName = 'file.pdf';
                $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filepdf']['tmp_name'], $pdfPath . $menuName);
                if ($result == 1) {
                    echo '<p class="error">File Uploaded!!</p>';
                } else {
                    echo '<p class="error">Si &#232; verficato un errore</p>';
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Now I want to do same work by cakephp.I have a clear concept on MVC.

Already I have made view.Now need help for controller and module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this plugin. https://github.com/Grafikart/CakePHP-Upload
For size restriction and if you are using cakephp 2.3 or higher put this new validation rule on your model:

```
public $validate = array(
        'image' => array(
        'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB'),
        'message' => 'L\'Image doit être inférieur à 1MB'
    )
);
```

otherwise you have to create a function to handle the validation. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods